# Android: Dynamically show all checkboxes in adapter onLongClick

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, custom-adapter

I was learning custom adapter concepts recently.

Problem is during onlongClick in a row,
I want to show checkboxes checked in the longclicked row, which is in `android:visibility="gone"` initially. And also to show checkboxes in other rows which are not clicked in unchecked state.

I changed some parts of this code here.
http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes.php

In simplerow.xml I made 
`android:visibility="gone"` initially.

Now I made a onLongClickListener inside `getView(...)` method

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener (new View.OnLongClickListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
         CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
         Planet planet = (Planet) cb.getTag();  
         planet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         planet.setChecked(true);
     }
});
```

Now the above code will affect only the longClicked row. How do I make changes in the non-clicked rows?

Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on long click did not work because the other rows have checkbox initially in `android:visibility="gone"`.

Please help. Is any other work around possible?

Answer (score 0):

ListView accompanies Adapter. All your model items would be inflated into the view items through the implemented method named `getView` from Adapter. If you want to update view without changing data, call [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) afterwards.